# adb shell am set-idle returns unknown command when testing app standby

Tags: adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

When running

> adb shell am set-idle package_name true

as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/testing/guide.html), it returns

> Error: unknown command 'set-idle'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ha! Found the answer right [here](https://plus.google.com/+MarcAshman/posts/Ez4DFxm3Eqe)

There is an error in the documentation page.
The correct command should be

> adb shell am set-inactive package_name true

Comment: Hi, I am using the same command with the emulator but it hangs forever. Does it take very long to execute ?